# Tag request: "question-answer voting" (or "post-voting"), to complement "comment-voting"

Tags: support, voting, comment-voting, tag-creation

There is currently the tag "comment-voting" for the comment voting system, but there is no equivalent tag for the system for voting on questions and answers.

Actually, there is the "voting" tag, but it seems to be not reflect the advent of comment voting.  Its current description seems to reflect only question and answer voting (actually, the badge descriptions do too..."Electorate - Of all your votes ever cast, 25% or more have been on questions alone and where you've voted on at 600 questions" "Suffrage - Used all of your 30 votes for a single day").

Really the structure here is:

- voting

  - question and answer voting
  - comment voting

...so there are 3 categories, and only two tags.

The missing tag, which I am proposing to have added, is "**question-answer-voting**".

("post-voting" is another option, but it is not intuitive that comments are not posts)

I understand question and answer voting is just referred to as "voting" in many places on this site because comment voting was implemented later (and for people who have been here since before that happened "voting" might to them just mean voting on questions and answers unless you explicitly add "comment-", but "voting" should really now refer to more than just the original system for questions and answers.

---

Edit:  In practice, in order to not upset previous tagging with "voting" (when it meant just question and answer voting), this would involve **renaming** *that* tag "question-answer-voting", then creating a new tag.  ...and in order to make sure people know that it is a new tag, maybe it should not be called "voting", but instead "voting-all".

Also, for easier use of the tag suggestions while typing, perhaps the tags should all start with "voting", which would make them:

- "voting-all"

  - "voting-questions-answers"
  - "voting-comments"

Comment: What is the actual request here ?

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd to add the tag "question-answer-voting".  I will edit to restate the title in the body.

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong when assuming the [voting tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/voting/info) includes comments. This tag is about **Question and Answers** already. This is why they created a [comment-voting](/questions/tagged/comment-voting) tag.

From the Voting tag wiki :

> Peer voting on questions and answers is the primary way users gain reputation, and also how many items are sorted to the top.

In other words the structure should remain like this :

- [voting](/questions/tagged/voting) : The action of voting on questions and answers
- [comment-voting](/questions/tagged/comment-voting) : The action of upvoting a cooment

You could always create a synonym for voting which would be [question-answer-voting](/questions/tagged/question-answer-voting) but I think it woudn't make it since it is a pleonasm  in this case.

Comment: I did *not* assume the voting tag includes comments.  I *specifically wrote* **"Actually, there is the "voting" tag, but it seems to be not reflect the advent of comment voting."**  That is part of the problem.

Comment: The fact remains, there can be a question on (1) voting on questions and answers, (2) voting on comments, or (3) **voting** (both).  You could apply both existing tags for the "both" case if we continue to insist that "voting" doesn't really mean (all) voting, but that is fighting the English language.

Comment: @A.M. My bad I actually misread your : "Really the structure here is" part.

Comment: I just edited the question to explain the problem with the current definition of "voting" tag in more detail (and what would need to happen to fix it).  Hopefully I have made it a little clearer now.

Comment: Would you have any idea why the comment system keeps stripping out my "@ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd"s?

Comment: You don't need them since you in my answer. I will automatically be notified when you comment here.

Comment: This is my multiple identical edit requests all over again!  Post...no response...post again thinking the system didn't work the first time.  (seems like another case for a pop-up!)  Thanks for clarifying!  :)